# How can I change the result of array push in php

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I have the following code to push data into an array if a condition is true however the result is not what I was hoping for;

```
         <?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM cart WHERE sess_id = '$sess_id'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);   
$items= array();

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row

   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
    $items[] = [
        'sku' => $row["prod_sku"], 
        'quantity' => (int)$row["prod_qty"]
    ];
}
if ($postage === 4.00){
    array_push($items, "sku_GSxe2lDNfK5b6E", 1);
}
}
        $conn->close();
             ?>
```

I would like the second record to look the same as the first, excluding the record information. Can someone please tell me how do go about it. I have not done a lot with arrays and I cant find the information I need anywhere. Thanks in advannce.

[{"sku":"sku_GGBzZqwz44UhRf","quantity":1},"sku_GSxe2lDNfK5b6E",1]

I want it to output like this

[{"sku":"sku_GGBzZqwz44UhRf","quantity":1}, {"sku":"sku_GSxe2lDNfK5b6E","quantity":1},]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your existing code pushes two separate values into the array:

```
if ($postage === 4.00){
    array_push($items, "sku_GSxe2lDNfK5b6E", 1);
}
```

You want to push another array into the array:

```
if ($postage === 4.00){
    array_push($items, ["sku" => "sku_GSxe2lDNfK5b6E", "quantity" => 1]);
}
```

Also please note that your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You should use prepared statements with bound parameters, via either [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). [**This post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has some good examples.

Comment: Thank you. That worked well. I knew that I had to fix the SQL thing. I will do that when I upload the site to a live environment.

Comment: _"I will do that when I upload the site to a live environment."_ Do it *before* you upload to live.